# Mariadb 10.3 on Debian 10 won't start anymore -

Tags: mariadb

on one of my servers there are Mariadb which stops with following status:

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.31 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-01 08:43:33 CEST; 9s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 7287 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 4ms

May 01 08:43:33 zabbix systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.31 database server...
May 01 08:43:33 zabbix sh[7287]: Failed to set environment: Access denied
May 01 08:43:33 zabbix systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 01 08:43:33 zabbix systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 08:43:33 zabbix systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.31 database server.
```

Everything was fine to yesterday. Mysql error logs is empty and this is only output which I have for now. There are a lot of disk space and RAM, so it shouldn't be a problem.
Can someone help to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Read the error log. Increase log verbosity if necessary.

Comment: but process of mysql is failed, so it won't log propably anything. Last line is ` mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended `

Comment: > `May 01 08:43:33 zabbix sh[7287]: Failed to set environment: Access denied`
What access? Check permissions and owners of all objects in the directory tree `/var/lib/mysql`, and also log directory/files worth checking. Also what if you start `mysqld-safe` from the root terminal, will it start and serve clients?

Comment: mysqld_safe started db but is it safety? Permissions to all files is set for mysql user proper

Comment: E.g. it successfully started by hand? Then that's a problem with the service manager. I doubt it has been broken "by itself". Likely there were some actions with the server: installation, configuration, unsafe resets, and so on. Can you please describe what *your* (or other administrator's) actions were immediately before it was broken?

Comment: No one use this server for few days, it happens late at night. Stats for config files isn't touched for few weeks when DB was created/updated. Maybe systemd is problem or this line about `ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION`

Comment: When running this line (unset-environment ...) from an unprivileged user the same error happens. So are you running in a special environment that drops privileges (container...)? Not having the line `PermissionsStartOnly=true` (which is present in default installation) would probably get this result too.

Comment: So `systemctl cat mariadb` added in the question would be a good idea, especially if there was snippet added which isn't provided by Debian.

Comment: `PermissionsStartOnly` is set to true. Set this line to false? Yes I'm using unprivleged container. Or maybe comment line about `unset-environment` ?